# Can not execute docker-compose in "Docker" image .yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a ".yml" for GitLab CI. I already have a "docker-compose.yml" which is executable in my local machine. However, when executing it in the Docker image, I encounter a few errors. These are the errors I get after executing "docker-comose up -d":

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d0de11250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d0de11250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d0de11250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnectionPool(host='docker', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3d0de11250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name does not resolve'))
```

This is how my '.gitlab-ci.yml' file looks like:

```
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind    
build:
  script:
    - apk add py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
    - pip3 install --upgrade pip
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem might be that `docker-compose` is not installed in your base image (which is `docker`).

#### Approach 1: Base image change

1. Your base image should be `docker:dind`
2. Install `docker-compose` by hand following the install guides in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose)

#### Approach 2: use compose base image

You could also try to use the official [`docker-compose`](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose) docker image in order to get this working, but (at the time of writing) I do not know how this behaves with GitLab CI